# Mysql - group by with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate a thread-like view

In the table I have from,to,date and some other columns

I want to output the rows grouped by from AND to

example data in DB

```
from,to,date
a,b,somedate
a,c,somedate
b,a,somedate
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    from, to, date 
FROM 
    data 
GROUP BY 
    from, to 
ORDER BY 
    date DESC;
```

The output I expect is like this: (where from and to is grouped together)

```
a,b,somedate
a,c,somedate

(b,a,somedate not shows because its in the a,b group)
```

but it doesn't ..

The general idea is to have a Messaging View "by user" .. 
where the list is sorted by recipients,date (not by message) ...

Comment: So you are associating `a,b` and `b,a`?

Comment: Yes correct like the `from` and `to` collum to handled as one for the grouping .. (somethings like that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one row returned for every `(from, to)` combination:

```
SELECT one, two, MIN(somedate) 
FROM
( SELECT `from` AS one, `to` AS two, somedate 
  FROM data 
  WHERE `from` <= `to`
UNION ALL
  SELECT `to`, `from`, somedate 
  FROM data 
  WHERE `from` > `to`
) AS tmp
GROUP BY one
       , two
ORDER BY one
       , two
```

or, if you want all records:

```
SELECT one, two, somedate 
FROM
( SELECT `from` AS one, `to` AS two, somedate 
  FROM data 
  WHERE `from` <= `to`
UNION ALL
  SELECT `to`, `from`, somedate 
  FROM data 
  WHERE `from` > `to`
) AS tmp
ORDER BY one
       , two
```

Comment: i managed to get the message out like this `code`SELECT * FROM maili where `from`='$user' or `to`='$user' GROUP BY GREATEST(`to`, `from`), LEAST(`to`, `from`) ORDER BY `sent``code` the output seems correct but i not get the last message body

Comment: @Nullx8: so you want only the latest record for every `(from,to)` combination?